# SQL grouping and sum to create new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Firstly, apologies I can't share code as I work with sensitive personal data so I have created a scenario based on a real issue I am having. I have a piece of code that when I run that outputs the following table.

```
Order ID    Product ID  Name    Sales
  1            1        Mike    7215
  1            2        Mark    13145
  2            1        Mike    2712
  2            2        Mark    12754
  3            1        Mike    1651
  3            2        Mark    5454
```

What I want to do is to be able to group ID's into higher level ID's, similar to local and regional data, you'd group the locals into regional.

Therefore in this scenario I want to be able to for any given list of ID's, be able to group them into the groups necessary, give them a new ID number and then SUM("Sales")

The two rows with 1001 are what I would want to be able to generate, they would be a grouping of ID's 1,2,3... I have a 100+ that group into about 8 bigger groups that I would need to do this for.

```
Order ID    Product ID  Name    Sales
  1            1        Mike    7215
  1            2        Mark    13145
  2            1        Mike    2712
  2            2        Mark    12754
  3            1        Mike    1651
  3            2        Mark    5454
  1001         1        Mike    11578
  1001         2        Mark    31353
```

Apologies if this isn't clear. I've tried my best to demonstrate without sharing code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I don't see any difference between your original data and desired data, except for the couple of extra rows.  Give us a sample of what you want the final results to look like.

Comment: Please see question amendments. I've tried to go into further detail.

Comment: How Mike and Mark are having same OrderId ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like:

```
Select * from MyTable --the original rows

Union all --append the newly created rows

Select 1001, ProductID, Name, sum(Sales) --sum of the sales by name and product for the IDs you selected
from MyTable
where OrderID in (1, 2, 3) -- or whatever IDs you want
group by ProductID, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your temp table has already been created/loaded in your stored proc, try something like this:

```sql
insert #SALES
select "Order ID"   = 1001           ,
       "Product ID" = t."Product ID" ,
       Name         = t.Name         ,
       Sales        = sum( t.Sales )
from #SALES t
group by t."Product ID" ,
         t.Name
```